# How to get multiple distinct columns from a table?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, jdbc, jdbctemplate

I need to get multiple distinct values from a table based on row .
Currently I am using two different queries to get the distinct values .

```
select distinct a from table;
select distinct b from table;
```

Is there a way to do this in a single query .
And I am using JDBCTemplate to fetch the data from these two queries . Will the single query be more performant that these 2 separate queries .
I am using postgresDB.

I came up with the following single query but I believe this is not performant .

```
select e1.a,e2.b from table t join (select distinct a,id from table)e1 on e1.id=t.id join (select distinct b,id from table)e2 on e2.id=t.id ;
```

Answer (score 1):

The two single queries are probably the best way.  You could also do this as:

```
select distinct 'a' as which, a from table
union all
select distinct 'b', b from table;
```